# How to access bios with lenovo G710 notebook on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop

I've tried pressing different buttons on startup but still cannot access the BIOS. How can I access it?

Comment: What specifically have you tried? Have you researched this on the manufacturer's support site?

Answer (score 5):

There is an old saying; *"If all else fails, read the manual."* This is why you should always do a little research before posting a question. I found this in about 5 minutes on the Lenovo site.

According to the [User Guide](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/g710_ug_en.pdf) for your laptop:

> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Press the Novo button and then select BIOS Setup.

The ***Novo*** button is located next to the power button.

Comment: Sad part is most laptops these days have the user manual right on the laptop!

Comment: That's certainly a polite way of saying RTFM. :)